# Graphing 3D function in Matlab from M file

Tags: matlab, optimization, graph

I'm trying to graph a nasty 3-dimension function that is defined in a separate M file.
It goes something like this:

```
function objfun = equilibrium(v)
x = v(1);
y = v(2);
%nasty function where objfun(x,y) = objfun
objfun = *nasty function in 2 variables*
```

Now I've been trying to plot f(x,y), but am not sure how to do this.

I had been trying this:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:1,0:1);
f = equilibrium([x,y]);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,f);
```

but obviously this does not give me a vector of @equilibrium values, so there is no surface to plot.

Comment: A better start would be to implement `equilibrium` such that it can deal with non-scalar `x`'s and `y`'s. In other words, the function would start with the prototype `function output = equilibrium(x, y)` and the implementation below that would allow `x` and `y` to be matrices. (If *absolutely* necessary it can be done by iterating over the elements of `x` and corresponding elements of `y` in a `for` loop, but that will be very slow - there are always ways you can "vectorize" your matlab code to deal with whole arrays at once.) Then your line after `meshgrid` would read `f = equilibrium(x,y);`

Comment: @jez: I actually did exactly this. I'm just iterating over a linspaces X and Y and recording the function value there.

Comment: Obviously, `x` and `y` are scalars in `equilibrium`. This does not necessarily mean that `objfun` (find another name to differentiate matlab `objfun`, eg `objFcn`) is scalar, but somehow indicates it. Also, the code to create a delunay triangulation does not work...   "delaunay([0,1],[0,1])
   Error using delaunay
   At least three input points must be provided to define a triangular mesh."

Comment: Define the step for meshgrid, otherwise you are going to create 4 points.

Comment: @Islands I'm afraid your stated implementation of `equilibrium` is not doing this.  It's operating on `x=v(1)` which is a single scalar x, and `y=v(2)` which is a single scalar y, at a time.  There's no way that is going to iterate over all the values of a meshgrid.  Also, note that at the moment "all the values" would only mean 4 values in any case: your current meshgrid outputs have only 2x2 resolution. I think you want `linspace(0, 1, resolution)` or `0:(1/resolution):1`  instead of just `0:1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
step = 0.25;
x = 0:step:1;
y = 0:step:1;

[XX YY] = meshgrid(x, y);

for i = 1:size(XX, 1)
   for j = 1:size(YY, 2)
      ZZ(i,j) = nasty_3_dimension_function([XX(i,j) YY(i,j)]);
   end
end

surf(XX, YY, ZZ)
```